# Python: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Tags: python, argv

```
import sys

a =int( sys.argv[1])

print "\nArguments -->",a , sys.argv[2]

print "\nNo of Argu ",  len(sys.argv), "\n"

print str(sys.argv)
```

command window output which i give is:

```
python testfunction.py a sf df sf
```

Whenevr the first argument is taken as 'a', it shows the error -->

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Newbie to python.
PLease provide the solution for how to handle this without try except

Also

When i dont give ant argument i should handle that too

Command window outout which i give:

python testfunction.py

Error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You know that `a` is not an integer, don't you? So what do you expect the program to do?

Comment: How can i handle that without try except ? please help me out

Comment: Why are you so scared of try/except? You can change it with if/else )

Comment: can you explain me how ? what command i should use . I am an newbie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not quite sure if you know what you are doing but let me clarify this for you:

```
a =int( sys.argv[1])
```

you expect your first argument to be of type integer. Which obviously is not the case since you call your script with the following arguments:

```
a sf df sf
```

Python trys to convert your first argument to an integer. Which fails.

A simple simple fix would be to make sure the first argument is an integer:

```
if sys.argv[1].isdigit():
    a = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print "First argument is not a digit"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Or surrond this with a try except block (which i would to)

```
try:
   a = int(sys.argv[1])
except ValueError:
   print "Stupid user, please enter a number"
   sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: When I dont give command line argument, I should handle that too       My command line iput i give is : python testfunction.py   Error: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 3):

You are trying `a =int( sys.argv[1])` which is taking from your command line `"a"` - this is not able to be converted to an integer using base 10 - i.e. it is not digits 0..9 !

To deal with this without using try..except you will have to check that all the characters in sys.argv[1] are in the range '0' to '9' **as characters** before calling the int().

Comment: i want that to be handled without try except ? please help me out in this

Comment: Strictly speaking, there can be also spaces and a minus sign in the string. On the whole, it is easier to call ``int()`` in a ``try`` than do all the checks it does manually.

Comment: How should i check that and i dont want to check before calling int ?

Comment: If you don't check you will get the error so have to try..execpt!

Comment: @Bogdan if there are spaces it will not be argv[1] unless it is enclosed in quotes - I did forget the minus sign in the first position only.  As you say try except is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

`int()` accepts a base as a second optional parameter.

```
a = int(sys.argv[1], 16) # == 10
```

You would still have to handle the exception for all other cases where the user might provide something that's entirely not an integer.

Comment: And will they not be surprised when they try running it with 100 as the first argument!

Comment: I am indeed guessing here that he wants hexadecimal, which might not be right :)

Answer (score 0):

Without `try/except`

```
if sys.argv[1].isdigit():
    a = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    #do smth if arg is not a number
    pass
```

Does work for positive integers only.

Comment: >>> argv='-33'
>>> argv.isdigit()
False # -33 is a valid int.

Comment: I do understand that. You answer is better than mine)

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing some-ones homework for them!

Comment: @Steve Barnes it is a really tiny homework. I think we can help him with such a little task)

Comment: thank you guys for helping me with this concept